# UnsatisfiedLinkError : Can't find dependent libraries , when try to load .dll file

Tags: windows, dll

I have found an open source library for working with TWAIN/WIA and JAVA,(https://github.com/dynarithmic/twain_library).

Library is written in C/C++ and they have use JNI to connect JAVA app with the library.

I keep getting the:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_361\bin\java.exe"  Exception in
> thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_361\bin\dtwainjni32.dll: Can't find dependent
> libraries     at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1853)  at
> java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:843)  at
> java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1134)    at
> Main.(Main.java:7)

I have put their .dll file in java.library.path and when I try to load the library through:

```
System.loadLibrary("dtwainjni32u");
```

I am using jdk1.8.0_361 to load the .dll file.

Comment: Use dependency walker et al to identify which DLLs it is missing.

Comment: Should I select .dll file to run with dependency walker?

Comment: The one you specify with `System.loadLibrary`, yes.

Comment: Dependency Walker is not responding whne i try to open .dll.

Comment: Then try with dependency explorer or dependencies.exe

Comment: When i open with dependenciesGUI,i get (? DTWAIN32U.dll) and (C:\Windwos\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll)

Comment: the ?DTWAIN32U.dll all module,machine,type..etc are with N/A

Comment: as for the  (C:\Windwos\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll) the type is executable and the checksum are all (correct)

Comment: Does this means that the dtwain32u.dll has no missing .dll-s?

Comment: That would mean it cannot find dtwain32u.dll, yes.